# How to retrieve parent node with child node that matching certain criteria using xquery?

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery

I'm trying to get partial data from my xml file,
The source file is like this:

```
<Odds>
  <Match ID="101" Time="A">
    <Event type="Home">
      <Score="1"/>
    </Event>
    <Event type="Away">
      <Score="2"/>
    </Event>
  </Match>
  <Match ID="102" Time="B">
    <Event type="Home">
      <Score="1"/>
    </Event>
    <Event type="Away">
      <Score="2"/>
    </Event>
  </Match>
</Odds>
```

I want to get the Odds, Match, Event, Score tags where Event type match "Home" only.
That is, the result is as below:

```
<Odds>
  <Match ID="101" Time="A">
    <Event type="Home">
      <Score="1"/>
    </Event>
  </Match>
  <Match ID="102" Time="B">
    <Event type="Home">
      <Score="1"/>
    </Event>
  </Match>
</Odds>
```

I'm fresh to XML, have read some books.
Tried to add criteria in WHERE of xquery and RETURN the parent node.
But the result always returns the Match with full child nodes.
That is, there is no difference between the result and the original one.
Is there any good way to do to get rid of those events that the type is not Home?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: How does your xquery expression look? It is probably correct, but the xquery implementation/tester you use also shows the parent and children of all returned nodes. Some do that

Comment: You should be asking this question with the "xslt" tag. An XSLT solution is trivial -- just a few lines. Would you be interested in an XSLT solution?

Comment: Sure! Any solution are welcome! It's also a new kind of learning. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with a huge file, I recommend you do use the following query:

```
for $match in $odds/Match
return <Match>
{$match/attribute()}
{$match/element()[@type = "Home"]}
</Match>
```

You can see this example live at http://28.io/sandbox/index#dwQcDXHxyl69BijJq6o5Mx8Fvrk=
Additionally, if you are looking to stream a large XML documents with Zorba, I would recommend you to check out the tutorial at http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/entry/2012/05/31/XML_Streaming

Answer (score 0):

If your XQuery processor support XQuery update, you can write the following:

```
  copy $odds-proj := $odds
  modify delete node $odds-proj//Event[@type = "Away"]
  return $odds-proj
```

You can try this example live at http://28.io/sandbox/index#QzdH/9PIwe11cJnVVZSqhpBdJkQ=

Comment: If you are working with a huge document, a more performant solution would be to do a transformation of your document. In that case the query would be a bit more complex.